# why my selenium code seems to be opening a new user profile window instead of using the specified user profile

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, browser, automation

Here's the java code I'm using:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class ExistingBrowser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Specify the path to the existing Chrome user profile directory
String userProfileDir = "C:\\Users\\VS\_\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 6";

        // Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
    
     // Create ChromeOptions instance and set the user data directory and the "no-first-run" flag
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + userProfileDir);
        options.addArguments("no-first-run");
    
        // Create a WebDriver instance with the ChromeOptions
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    
        // Perform further operations using the driver
        driver.get("https://www.example.com");
    }

}
```

I have verified that the userProfileDir path is correct and points to an existing user profile directory on my system. However, every time I run the code, it opens a new Chrome window instead of using the specified user profile.

I have also tried using the --no-first-run argument in the ChromeOptions but it didn't make any difference.

I'm using Selenium version **3.141.59** and ChromeDriver version **114.0.5735.90** My Chrome browser version is **114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)
**

I am attempting to open an existing Chrome user profile using Selenium in Java, but I am encountering difficulties. I want to achieve the following behavior:

- Launch Chrome using an existing user profile, preserving all saved data, bookmarks, and preferences associated with that profile.
- Ensure that the opened Chrome window is connected to the specified user profile and not creating a new profile.

Any help or suggestions on how to open an existing Chrome user profile using Selenium in Java would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!